# Markdown help - page bug

Tags: bug, design

On the [Markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), when scrolled down, the right navigation pane (Code and Preformatted Text, Linebreaks, Italics and Bold, Links ...) covers Stack Overflow's sister sites links under the heading "Other" namely

1. [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)
2. [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)
3. [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
4. [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

This can be improved!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you take screenshot and specify which browser you're using and what platform?

Comment: I can reproduce on Firefox 22.0 (current version) and internet explorer 10 (current version)

Comment: I can reproduce in Chrome 28 Linux. It only happens in narrower browser windows where the help page lays out with a wider minimum width than other pages on the site.

Comment: [Repro with IE 10 on Win RT.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/14HkN.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens on the help page specifically because there are over-sized elements in the page that force a wider minimum width than usual. However the main container isn't growing, the main elements are just overflowing. Unfortunately along with the page content, the footer decides it can grow too -- except in growing it doesn't get a bigger container it just overflows.

I can reproduce in Chrome 28 on Linux.

Here is what a normal page footer looks like:

[image: normal page (no scroll)]

Here is what the broken footer looks like on the markdown help page:

[image: markdown help page (scrolled right)]

Comment: My footer looks normal (like the first image) but I still get the navigation panel over the top of the footer